# Current date field in array read by PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array made up of dated events that I list on a webpage using PHP to generate the page that shows a date sorted table. I am trying to insert the PHP time() function, in a specific format that works for me, into one specific record of the text (CSV) array so that every time someone opens this page, this one specific record always reads with the current date in the format that I need. I have tried many variations of

```
 <?php print ((time() + '39681000000')/1000000); ?>
```

Both with and without the PHP open and close tags, and many other variations, but with no success. The record just shows a blank field with this function in it with the tags and just shows the code without the tags. The PHP function works fine stand alone, but will not work when inserted in the record field. It does not seem that I can insert any PHP function, let alone this one, into the record field and have it work, so it does not seem to be a problem with how this function is written.

I have also tried to declare this as a Global variable at the top of the page and then call it in this field, but that does not work. I have tried the now() function with no joy either.

Thanks,
Stan...

Comment: Can you show a little more context? (e.g. the code you are using to output the table)

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the quick response. The test page that I have set up is located here: http://www.seocom.com/postcard/000showtest.php The record that I want to show with the current date is the one that that is currently on the top. Thanks again, Stan...

Comment: @Stan If the PHP code is embedded in a field in the CSV, you will have to use the [eval()](http://php.net/eval) construct in order to execute the PHP code.  Standard disclaimer: eval is DANGEROUS.  Also, if the server isn't 64-bit, then the time you are creating may be too big.  I'm not seeing what the `+ '39681000000')/1000000)` is supposed to accomplish, but I'm tired today.  Note, PHP's `time()` function returns the number of *seconds* since epoch, not microseconds like Javascript and some other languages.

Comment: Hi Stan, I see what you are talking about, but it would be helpful in figuring out the problem to actually see the PHP code (the code surrounding the one line of code that you put in your original post).

Comment: Hi Drew, the original csv file is created by Excel. The rest of the records that are listed, have a hidden field that is formatted to a date field in Excel's 5 digit date format that everything is sorted on. The + '39681000000')/1000000) just changes the Unix time stamp into the same format as the Excel produced records. Without having a chance yet to look it up, why is the eval() construct dangerous? Thanks, Stan...

Comment: Hi Joe, I thought that by posting the web address that anyone could view the page source info in their browser and would be better than pasting a lot of code here?? I may be wrong of course...Thanks, Stan...Of Course, I do realize that I am wrong as the PHP code just produces an HTML Page as a source...I can be a dummy sometimes...Stan...

Comment: @Stan See php.net/eval for their cautions on why it is/can be dangerous.  As stated, if you have no other choice, use it, just know that if you allow any user to upload CSV, they can put nasty PHP code in that could be malicious.  But if you are trying to put the date into Excel ahead of time, you probably have no choice.  I suppose if you are just trying to print the current time for a given row all the time, you could just use some other value like `${DATE}` and you can search for that in PHP and `str_replace` it with the current time rather than eval'ing code.

Comment: @Stan, also if you put "@drew010" or more generally "@username" when you comment in response to someone, they will see a notification about the comment, otherwise they don't know you replied and have provided additional info.

Comment: @drew10 thanks for the tip on replying with "@username". I did not know that...I will check out the rest of your answer tomorrow when I have more time than right now.

Comment: @JoeM. I tried to post the code, but did not have enough room in the comments box. I tried to edit my original post with the 4 indents, but all it worked on was the first line and not the rest. I have posted it as  text file that can be found here http://www.seocom.com/postcard/000showtest.txt Thanks, Stan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case a string replace might be the best option (like mentioned above by drew). Try to remove the PHP code from the CSV file and replace it with something like `${DATE}`, then put something like this in your while loop that imports the CSV file right after you set $line:

```
$line = str_replace('${DATE}', (time() + 39681000000/1000000), $line);
```

Comment: Hi Joe & Drew @drew010 Just wanted to get back to you both and thank you very much for all the help. Your combined thoughts have worked out fine. Just as a side note for anyone who might use this in the future though, I had to modify Joe's "one liner" above as I got errors with the time function & adjustment formula located in the str_replace function. I had to assign this item to a variable at the top of the page first, and then use that variable in the str_replace later on. But, it works great and hopefully someone else can use it along the way too. Again, Thank You Very much to you both.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looks like I had an extra close parentheses I didn't need in the line, changed it now. Goodluck!